# Save xlsx file using python win32com

Tags: python

I am trying to save an excel file which is already open using these lines

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pywintypes

xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

try:
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks('MyData.xlsx')
except pywintypes.com_error:
    print('The file MyData.xlsx is not open.')
    exit()

wb.Save()
xlapp.Quit()
```

But I got this message printed at console `The file MyData.xlsx is not open.` although the file is open !!

Comment: Are you trying to open an existing Excel file and then save it OR are you trying to create a new Excel file and then save it?

Comment: No the excel is already open and need to save it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new .xlsx file, try this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pywintypes
import os
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()

xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

try:
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Add()
except pywintypes.com_error:
    print('The file MyData.xlsx is not open.')
    exit()

wb.SaveAs(current_working_directory+'/MyData.xlsx')
xlapp.Quit()
```

If you're trying to open an existing .xlsx file and then save it (as maybe a different name), try this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pywintypes
import os
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()

xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

infile  = '/MyData.xlsx'
outfile = '/MyData2.xlsx'

try:
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(current_working_directory+infile)
except pywintypes.com_error:
    print('The file MyData.xlsx is not open.')
    exit()

wb.SaveAs(current_working_directory+outfile)
xlapp.Quit()
```

Comment: The excel is already open and I need to save the excel file itself.

Comment: Show the code where you open the file